# Batch Script to Take A Part of Folder Names and Create New Folders From Them

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, script, cmd.exe

I need to make a batch script that takes a part of a folder name and creates a new folder
with that part of the name, then moves the original folder into it.

An example is :
Folder "`ABC - DEF`" gets a new folder made by delimiting the "`-`", then
the new folder "`ABC`" has the original folder "`ABC - DEF`" moved into it.

I am having problems making a script that can work with many folders to do this.

What I currently have is:

```
@echo off

C:
cd C:\Folders
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%A in ('dir /ad /b "C:\Folders*"') do (
   
echo folder found  %%A
for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set fname=%%~nB
for /f "delims=" %%C in ("%%A") do set fextn=%%~xC
for /f "tokens=1* delims=-" %%D in ("!fname!") do set 

folname=%%D
echo folder name !folname!
if not exist "!folname!" (
     echo Folder !folname! does not exist, creating
     md "!folname!"
   ) else (
     echo Folder !folname! exists
   )

   echo Moving file %%A to folder !folname!
   move "%%A" "!folname!"
   )

echo Finished
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```powershell
@echo off 

cd /d "%~dp0"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /d %%i in ("* - *") do 2>nul (

     echo\ & set "_Folder=%%~i"
     echo\Folder found: ...\!_Folder:*\=!
     cd /d "%~dp0!_Folder:*- =!\." ) && 2>nul ( 
     echo\Folder "!_Folder:*- =!" exists... & cd.. ) || 2>nul (
     echo\Folder: ...\!_Folder:*- =! does not exist, creating...
     mkdir "%~dp0!_Folder:*- =!" & echo\Moving file ..\!_Folder:*- =! to folder !_Folder:*- =! 
     move "%%~fi" "%CD%\!_Folder:*- =!" && echo\Moving file "%%~nxi" to folder "..\!_Folder:*- =!".. 
     
    ) 
    )
    
echo\Finished & %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -t 60 & endlocal && goto=:EOF
```

This was done assuming the following:

- Layout in the folder names: **`ABCspace-space123`**
- The bat is saved and running in the folder where executions will take place:

  ```powershell
  cd /d "%~dp0"
  ```

---

**1.** Use `cd /d substring` and `cd..` to verify that the desired folder already exists:

```powershell
cd /d "c:\folder\subfolder\ABC - 123"
cd /d "%~dp0!_Folder:*- =!\." ...   cd..
```

**2.** Use execution blocks with operators to take over `cd/copy/mkdir` actions based in:

- `return 0`/`return non 0`, also omit any possible message error **`2>nul`**:

  ```powershell
  cd /d "%~dp0!_Folder:*- =!\."

   ) && 2>nul (
     ↑↑
      ⤷ return 0 in last execution, so do:
      echo\Folder "!_Folder:*- =!" exists...
      cd..

   ) || 2>nul ( 
     ↑↑
      ⤷ return non 0 in last execution, so do:

      echo\Folder: ...\!_Folder:*- =! does not exist, creating...
      mkdir "%~dp0!_Folder:*- =!"
      echo\Moving file ..\!_Folder:*- =! to folder
  ```